# Python Selenium Mod Header

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to add a mod header to my firefox instance. I've looked around SO and seems like the below should be the solution but I get an error that is asking me for some kind of install file.

I navigate to here and download the firefox mod header add in.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-header-value/
Which gives me an xpi file: **modify_header_value_http_headers-0.1.3-an+fx.xpi**

```
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
path_modify_header = '/Users/whitney_chia/Downloads/modify_header_value_http_headers-0.1.3-an+fx.xpi'
fp.add_extension(path_modify_header)

fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.count", 1)
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.action0", "Add")
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.name0", "MyHeaderName") # Set here the name of the header
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.value0", "MyHeaderValue") # Set here the value of the header
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.enabled0", True)
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.config.active", True)
fp.set_preference("modifyheaders.config.alwaysOn", True)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get("MyURL")
```

The error I get is the below:

```
AddonFormatError: ("[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\WHITNE~1\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmp0ou6fmws.modify_header_value_http_headers-0.1.3-an+fx.xpi\\\\install.rdf'", <traceback object at 0x000000000676D588>)
```

It seems to be looking for an "install.rdf" within the .xpi file. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? The .xpi file is like a zip file from what I've read, do I need to unzip it first? Even then I don't see an install.rdf in it.

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use the modifier headers while opening a browser is by specifying the browser profile.
IN your case , you can add the mod-header as the extension to your Firefox.Then in your script, you can specify the ff profile you are going to use.
You will get the ff profile by clicking Windows+R and give the "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\"
Now you will be shown the profiles, select the latest file and go to extensions folder.There you can see your mod-header .xpi file.
You can specify the path in your script while opening browser which opens with modifier header.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by extracting modheader.zip file and then creating a new compressed (zip) folder and putting all the extracted data inside it. Then instead of passing modheader.xpi file as parameter use modheader.zip.